# wlan0 not showing on ifconfig/iwconfig, even with TP-link wireless adapter connected

Tags: wifi

I just got a TP-Link wifi adapter, and followed a YouTube tutorial on how to set it up. It worked fine at first, and showed Mode: Montitor when I finished. However after messing around for a bit, I restarted my Kali Linux (on VM) and now I can not get it to work again. wlan0 does not show on ifconfig nor iwconfig.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is your wireless adaptor known to be call **wlan0**?
Try the `ip a` command to get confirmation on this.

Comment: @JeremyBoden Only lo and eth0 are showing when I write ip a.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my TPlink wifi receiver . The issue was the dkms was not installed in the system. By installing the required dkms from apt and a reboot it was running.